# After an acquisition, are public firms compelled to report their quarterly performance immediately?

Tags: stocks, regulation

Recently, the company Fastly Inc (NYSE: FSLY) reported preliminary results for their 3rd quarter.

On their [official website](https://investors.fastly.com/news/news-details/2020/Fastly-Provides-Preliminary-Third-Quarter-Revenue-Results/default.aspx), they made the following statement:

> SAN FRANCISCO--(BUSINESS WIRE)-- Fastly, Inc. (NYSE: FSLY), in fulfillment of its obligations to promptly file a resale registration statement on Form S-3 in connection with its successful acquisition of Signal Sciences on October 1, today announced preliminary revenue results for the third quarter ended September 30, 2020.

Is it common practice for businesses to release their financials following a merger or acquisition? Or did their financial staff simply decide to go ahead for the sake of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it typical for companies to announce their financials after a merger/acquisition?

Yes, unless the other company is insignificant. Shareholders - the owners - must be informed and if I merge or acquire another company my financials change SIGNIFICANTLY. This may not be the case if MS buys a smaller game studio i.e., but if you buy something that does a large change to your balance sheet, your fiduciary duties definitely include updating the information asap.

Comment: Can you include a citation to the SEC regulation that specifies this?

Comment: Nope. Not a lawyer. Not my job to use google for you.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, you literally provided no evidence other than your word. I believe everyone who views this post in the future would also benefit greatly if you at least included some semblance of a justification - do you personally have a lot of experience in the corporate financial world that has lead you to this conclusion? Or is this something you just "think" is a "fiduciary duty" (as opposed to know for sure)?

Comment: Nope, sorry, just working as a broker 30 years ago and active in the markets ever since. Keep your owners informed is a basic principle.